# Gatsby Cloud Build Failing with "Out of Memory" Error

Tags: gatsby, node-modules, static-site, gatsby-image, gatsby-cloud

I'm running into an "Out of Memory" issue during my Gatsby Cloud builds for my site. It will stop running on the "Rewriting Compilation Hashes" step after building the JavaScript bundles.

This all started to happen after I uploaded a 70mb .mp4 video to my assets folder in Gatsby and then pushed to GitHub. My overall folder is 1.11 GB
It failed on the preview build and I have not merged it into main as it's separated on its own branch.  I have since deleted that video from my project, cached the website, deleted the node modules and reinstalled npm.

However, I still cannot get it to build on gatsby build or obviously when I try and push it to the cloud. Locally, it builds sometimes but sometimes stops on run page queries...
Any suggestions? I'm relatively new to Gatsby and am desperately trying to get this problem solved. Thanks in advance!

[Gatsby Build Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/304MA.png)